# Adding up variables in a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, int, java.util.scanner

HI i am making a code where you can type in how many people you want and see their BMI, the thing is i want my code to sum up the total BMI of all the people and then dividing it with the total amount of people typed in.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static double calculate(int weight, int height) {
        weight = 100*100*weight;
        height = height * height;                                       
        return weight / height;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int sum = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter numbers here");
        Scanner people = new Scanner((new Scanner(System.in)).nextLine());     
        while (people.hasNextInt()) {
            sum += people.nextInt();
        }

        for (int x =1; x <= sum; x++) {


            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("hur lång är du i cm?");              
            int height = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("hur tung är du i kg?");                 
            int weight = scanner.nextInt();

            double BMI = calculate(weight, height);                    
            System.out.println(BMI);

            System.out.println(+x);
            if (x == sum) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you struggling with?

Comment: I am struggling with adding up the total peoples BMI and dividing it with how many people you input

Comment: 3 scanner objects in a single method.... looks weird....

Answer (score 1):

I can see several issues with this code...

- You are using multiple instances of `Scanner`. You should be using only one.
- You're not keeping track of the total BMI. You'll want this if you are going to print the total average BMI. Outside of the for loop, you need to initialize a variable `double totalBMI = 0` and inside the for loop, add each person's BMI to the total.
- You are summing the "numbers" but I'm not sure what those numbers represent. From the way the code is written, it looks like they are numbers of people. Are they? If so, the variable `sum` would be better named `numberOfPeople`.
- You should not need to `break` out of the for loop. It has an exit condition.
- The BMI calculation seems suspicious to me. If you name your variables more accurately, it'll be easier to spot mistakes. I would write:

  ```
  public static double bmi(double weightInKg, double heightInCm) {
      double heightInMeters = heightInCm / 100d;

      // As per https://www.nhs.uk/chq/Pages/how-can-i-work-out-my-bmi.aspx
      return weightInKg / heightInMeters / heightInMeters;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Let's clean up your code, shall we?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class BMICalculator {
    public BMICalculator() {
        try ( // use a "try with resources" to make sure the scanner is properly closed at the end
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);     
                ) {
            double totalBMI = 0d; // declare a variable to hold our total BMI - notice properly named variables don't need comments
            System.out.println("Enter number of people (0 to exit):");
            int numPeople = scanner.nextInt();
            if (numPeople == 0) { return; }
            System.out.println(""); // print a blank line just for looks

            for (int x = 0; x < numPeople; x++) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Enter measurements for person %d (Whole numbers only)", (x+1))); // x started at 0 so we need to a 1
                System.out.println("hur lång är du i cm?");              
                int height = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println("hur tung är du i kg?");                 
                int weight = scanner.nextInt();

                double BMI = calculate(weight, height);  
                totalBMI += BMI;                  
                System.out.println(String.format("BMI for person %d = %3.3f", (1 + x), BMI));
                System.out.println(""); // print a blank line just for looks
            }
            System.out.println(String.format("Average BMI = %3.3f.", (totalBMI / numPeople)));
        }
    }

    public double calculate(int weight, int height) {
        double _weight = (double)100*100*weight;
        double _height = (double)height * height;                                       
        return _weight / _height;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { new BMICalculator(); }
        });
    }
}
```